# How to make transition from Rigid Active Body to Animated

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am making animation of box opening. I have lock which I want to unlock and throw in air, that is animated. Then it would be easier to make it rigid body so it only falls on ground instead of me animating it. But don't know if it's possible and worth trying.

Comment: yes there is an Animated option in the Rigid Body panel  you can keyframe it so that ii is activated when the animation must play, then deactivate when the physics act on the object

Comment: Oh, so basically just check "animate property" on Dynamic and Animated. That was so logical. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an *Animated* option in the *Rigid Body* panel you can keyframe it so that it is activated when the animation must play, then deactivate when the physics must act on the object.